# diff to web display?

Tags: c#, .net, diff, highlighting

I want to create a diff between two pieces of text (code but i may also want forum post) and highlight the difference in a webpage. What lib might i use to do that? I dont mind if highlighting is done in javascript. I am using asp.net with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [jsdifflib](http://snowtide.com/jsdifflib)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/) library.

It is the same diff'ing library that is used by [CodePlex.com](http://codeplex.com) to show source code diffs.  You can see an example of its output [here](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/diff/file/view/dcde14f5d330?fileId=DiffPlex.ConsoleRunner%2fProgram.cs).